# Non-Transparent Text with html image and psuedo css classes

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I need to place NON-transparent text on an image. This image is defined in the html. (This is so it can be dynamic). I style the transparency with an `:after` pseudo element. I would like to have text on this image. apprecaited

However, the problem I'm running into is that the text inherits the transparency. All of the other solutions I have found either define the picture in CSS or don't use a picture at all. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: A colored transparency is desired.

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="red-square-parent">
  <%= image_tag 'infos/home/teaching-3.jpg' %>
  <div class="centered">Don't Apply Transparency to me!</div>
</div>
```

```
#red-square-parent img{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: none;
}

// Overlay
#red-square-parent:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  background: rgba($comp-color-red, 0.7);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue is that you're applying transparency to the parent element. Just target the image specifically for transparency:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/on3ew4z5/)

```css
#red-square-parent img{
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#red-square-parent div{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6" id="red-square-parent">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/eTmzQ.jpg"/>
  <div class="centered">Don't Apply Transparency to me!</div>
</div>
```

In order to apply a coloured filter over this image, you will not be applying `background-color` as this will not change the color of the image at all.

What you instead need to do it a bit complicated, but you must apply a `filter` to the image.

I would recommend using a tool such as this: [CSS Generator - Filter](http://angrytools.com/css-generator/filter/) to get the desired color effect you want.

When you have the desired `filter`, update your code to look something like this (using the code generated from the [CSS Generator - Filter](http://angrytools.com/css-generator/filter/) site. See my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln495xf8/1/)

```css
#red-square-parent img{
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.5;
  
  /* Filter  */
  filter: grayscale(50%) opacity(1) brightness(100%) contrast(100%) hue-rotate(500deg);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(50%) opacity(1) brightness(100%) contrast(100%) hue-rotate(500deg);
}

#red-square-parent div{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6" id="red-square-parent">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/eTmzQ.jpg"/>
  <div class="centered">Don't Apply Transparency to me!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I would like it to be a colored filter. Using that JSFiddle with `background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.3);` instead of `opacity` does not apply anything. Is there a way to do it with a color?

Comment: Hi, so background-color isn't going to do anything, as you don't really want to change the color of the background so much as change the color of the image. I'll update my answer on how to do this, it's a bit complicated tbh

Comment: Thanks much for the updated answer. Is there no way to specify the exact rgb value? I had a specific color pallet in mind. If not, perhaps I should apply a transformation on the image itself and not worry about doing it in CSS.

Comment: Not that I've discovered, and I've been trying to figure it out for a few months now.. haha.. I suppose you could overlay a `div` with `background-color:rgba(0,0,255,0.3);` but this may cause issues.. but feel free to give it a go!

Comment: Maybe sus this: https://bryanlrobinson.com/blog/how-to-css-after-elements-for-background-overlays/ (It's gross though, looks like you may need to hardcode all your `height`'s and `width`'s manually twice)